# What is the best StateManagement tool/library for heavy Data load and crud Operation Angular7 based Application

Tags: javascript, rxjs, frontend

I have **Single Page Angular(SPA) 7** Application with **bulk data load** and with **Crud Operation** like Schema based Form Generation,Angular Tree Operation,Multi Grid View Forms,Popup Form etc. etc. with having different different Angular Services and Components.

So now i am planning to implement Front **State Managemement** in Application with all CRUD Operation.So that application load will decrease,rather than storing data in Services global variables etc etc.

I am not able to decide as per my knowledge which all library are available for State Management and which one will best for Angular7 based application.

Please give me suggestion and provide some useful links.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say ngxs, but your question  is off topic on so, because opinion based, I am sorry. All the best

Comment: https://ngrx.io/

Answer (score 0):

NGRX is one of the state management libraries you can use, but if you want a much simpler solution, take a look at 
[XSM](https://github.com/peterluhub/xsm)